# Why can't I set Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat to some valid formats?

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I'm trying to use an Excel Macro to reformat a spreadsheet exported using OLE-Automation

The following code works OK:

```
Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "#,##0.0000000"
Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
    xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
```

if I change the ReplaceFormat to

```
Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = "#,##0.0"
```

to display only 1 decimal place, I get an error 1004 (Application-defined or object-defined error). "0.0" fails as well.

I can set the cell format (Cells.NumberFormat) to "#,##0.0"

I have only tried this against Excel-2003 as it is the only version I have available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found part of the answer. For this to work, the NumberFormat must already exist in the workbook.

A work-around is to set the format of a cell to "#,##0.0", then do the replace:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").NumberFormat = "#,##0.0" 
Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "#,##0.0000000"
Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
    xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
```

There doesn't seem to be any Collections that allow me to get at the custom number formats ([According to this site anyway](http://members.optushome.com.au/anandasim/excel.htm)).

I discovered this when setting Application.FindFormat to a new format started throwing errors!

Answer (score 1):

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

To avoid this error you must have existing cells with both used formats at least once. I have first rows for column names so they have only string values and setting first two column names to dateformat won't have any visible affect on my sheet data.

```vba
Sub datum_popravak_rucno()
    ' add find format to cell A1
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    ' add replace format to cell B1
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"
    ' define find format
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    ' define replace format
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"
    ' do replace on all cells
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
        xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
End Sub
```

Works in Excel 2003, 2007, 2010!