# VBA Currency NumberFormat Error - Excel

Tags: object, currency, number-formatting

I've a worksheet with many cells formated as currency and i want modify the currency format through a combobox,

First i use this code to get the inicial currency type/format,

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()

inicial = Me.ComboBox1.Value

Select Case inicial

Case "EUR"

oldFormat = "#.##0 €"

Case "GBP"

oldFormat = "[$£-809]#.##0"

Case "USD"

oldFormat = "#.##0 [$USD]"

End Select

End Sub
```

The oldformat variable is a global variable,

```
Public oldformat As String
```

After that i want to do a find using oldformat variable and a replace using a newformat variable,

```
 Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim newFormat As String

'On Error Resume Next

 newValue = Me.ComboBox1.Value

 Select Case newValue

 Case "EUR"

 newFormat = "#.##0 €"

 Case "GBP"

 newFormat = "[$£-809]#.##0"

 Case "USD"

 newFormat = "#.##0 [$USD]"

 End Select

 'Set rNextCell = Application.FindFormat

 For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

 Application.FindFormat.Clear
 Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = oldFormat
 Application.ReplaceFormat.Clear
 Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = newFormat

 ws.Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
 :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True

Next ws
End Sub
```

I read the new value through the user choice on the combobox.

But this not work at all, the variables oldformat and newformat receive the correct values but i got a error on,

```
Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = oldformat
Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = newFormat
```

Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Is there any way to pass the newformat and oldformat value to the Numberformat property?

Or someone have another away to do this?

Link for exemple file,
https://www.dropbox.com/s/sdyfbddxy08pvlc/Change_Currency.xlsm

I apreciate any help, i m a little bit new on VBA.

I apologize if there are any errors in English, is not my natural language.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459524/why-cant-i-set-application-replaceformat-numberformat-to-some-valid-formats

Comment: I already have the formats on the custom format box, and still get the error. you can see in the exemple file.

Comment: What decimal delimiter and number group delimiter are setted in your system? VBA will ever use the english format codes, so "#.##0,00" will *not* work correctly, if decimal delimiter is comma and number group delimiter is dot. Then "#,##.00" has to be used, if 1.000,00 should be the result.

Comment: Here my regional settings https://www.dropbox.com/s/4u44a8l1snsqr6b/Regional.png and the error on VBA https://www.dropbox.com/s/aysyyc1smcphslf/VBA.png I change the formats to "#,##.0 €" "[$£-809]#,##.0" and "#,##.0 [$USD]". I add them to the custom format box, https://www.dropbox.com/s/ad8vanm2hwtsudb/Formatbox.png

Comment: No, you should not change the format codes in the custom format box. You should use the English codes in the VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded the file. Then change the Code to:

```
Public oldFormat As String

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim newFormat As String

    'On Error Resume Next

newValue = Me.ComboBox1.Value

Select Case newValue

Case "EUR"

    newFormat = "#,##0 $"

Case "GBP"

    newFormat = "[$£-809]#,##0"

Case "USD"

    newFormat = "#,##0 [$USD]"

End Select

'Set rNextCell = Application.FindFormat

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

     ws.Range("XFD1048576").NumberFormat = oldFormat
     ws.Range("XFD1048576").NumberFormat = newFormat
     ws.Range("XFD1048576").NumberFormat = "General"

     Application.FindFormat.Clear
     Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = oldFormat
     Application.ReplaceFormat.Clear
     Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = newFormat

     ws.Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
     :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True

    Next ws
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()

inicial = Me.ComboBox1.Value

Select Case inicial

Case "EUR"

    oldFormat = "#,##0 $"

Case "GBP"

    oldFormat = "[$£-809]#,##0"

Case "USD"

    oldFormat = "#,##0 [$USD]"

End Select

End Sub
```

Now it runs without errors.

But one issue is there yet. If the user defined format equals the default currency format, then Excel (Excel! not VBA) will not set the user defined format but the default currency format. This is for Germany in VBA "#,##0 $". With me this was the case with #.##0 € which is one of the German currency formats. So for me is EUR "#,##0 $" in VBA.

Greetings

Axel

Comment: I will tray later on, then i say something. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i was on vacations. I use your code on my file and nothing happens... No errors no results, nothing. Can you help me?

Comment: I'm from Portugal. #.##0,00[$€-816]

Comment: Then try with "#,##0[$€-816]" for EUR in oldFormat. Or format the values with $USD #.##0 [$USD] first and try then. The program looks at first, wether it finds values in one of the oldFormat settings. If it finds none, it does nothing.